# GAE Jersey RESTful service POST JSON

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, rest, jersey

I am trying to write a service which will accept a JSON or XML object in a POST request. I have successfully written a GET request handler that will return my object as XML or JSON as requested in the header's accept. When I POST to the service with JSON as the body of the request the Java Object in my POST method is not filled with the values from the json.

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void postUser(@Context HttpServletRequest Req, User user) 
{
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try 
    {
        pm.makePersistent(user);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        pm.close();
    }

}
```

When I break in the POST method the Java object "user" of type User has null values for the properties. The object is not null itself, just the properties.

This is the JSON submitted by POST

```
{"user":{"logon":"kevin","password":"password","personid":"xyz"}}
```

And here is my class

```
package com.afalon.cloud.contracts;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Extension;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class User {

 @Persistent
 @XmlElement(name="logon")
 private String logon;

 @Persistent
 @XmlElement(name="password")
 private String password;

 @Persistent
 @XmlElement(name="personid")
 private String personid;

 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    @XmlElement(name="userid")
 private String userid;

 public User () {}

 public void setLogOn(String value) {
  logon = value;
 }

 public String getLogOn() {
  return logon;
 }

 public void setPassword(String value) {
  password = value;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }

 public void setPersonId(String value) {
  personid = value;
 }

 public String getPersonId() {
  return personid;
 }

 public String getUserId() {
  return userid;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe no-one answered my question because the problem has such an obvious solution!

I can answer my own question after I noticed my mistake.

The JSON body I was submitting was formatted as a list of `User` objects so if I edit

```
{"user":{"logon":"kevin","password":"password","personid":"xyz"}}
```

to

```
{"logon":"kevin","password":"password","personid":"xyz"}
```

everything works because my @POST handler is not expecting a list of `User` objects. Alternativly I could adapt my @POST handler to accept a `List<User>` parameter!

Comment: Actually you were posting an object with `user` property that contained "User". Objects are denoted by {}, arrays by []. There is no List per se.